# Formatting the display of all files in directory and subdirectories

Tags: awk, find, mount

I want to display all files in directory and subdirectory between the bytesize 30000 and 50000.

I want to display my files the following way:

```
file1.xxx     md5sum     bytesize
file2.xxx     md5sum     bytesize
```

Here is the code I have so far (it has to be one single command):

```
find /mnt/analysis -size +30000c -size -50000c -exec md5sum {} \; -exec ls -l {} \; | awk '{print $1 $5 $9}'
```

Output:

```
2fc863d4e42fcced35ce17cdbb9cb623
-rwxrwxrwx33673/mnt/analysis/bla/twelve.png
a952105e64609de5149db2da08e3256c
-rwxrwxrwx41412/mnt/analysis/bla/thirteen.png
```

Desired output:

```
/mnt/analysis/bla/twelve.png 2fc863d4e42fcced35ce17cdbb9cb623 33673

/mnt/analysis/bla/thirteen.png a952105e64609de5149db2da08e3256c 41412
```

The problem is that the awk gets done on both exec files which is why the permissions also get in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you live with the md5sum first, like

```
find /mnt/analysis -size +30000c -size -50000c -type f | xargs stat -c"echo \$(md5sum %n) %s" | sh
```

or with a minus sign

```
find /mnt/analysis -size +30000c -size -50000c -type f | xargs stat -c"echo %n \$(md5sum <%n) %s" | sh
```

(that you could delete by appending a `tr -d -`, given no file name has one, of course)

Comment: I used the method with the minus sign and it worked. The only thing i did extra was pipe it again after sh and do an awk like | awk '{print $1 "\t" $2 "\t" $4}'. This gets the minus sign away.

Answer (score 0):

To reformat things the way you want it, I would wrap the code into a "find shell"; it boils down to a single "printf" command with three arguments:

1. the filename
2. the md5sum of the file
3. the size of the file

The `find` command passes each matched filename into the "find shell" as parameter (`$1`), so that's what each printf argument works on:

```
find /mnt/analysis -size +30000c -size -50000c -type f -exec \
  sh -c 'printf "%s %s %d\n" \
         "$1" \
         "$(md5sum "$1" | awk "{print \$1}")" \
         "$(stat -c %s "$1")"' find-sh {} \;
```

I added a `-type f` restriction to your original find command, in order to get a meaningful result from md5sum (and the call to `stat` to get the size).  I've broken out the "find shell" command onto multiple lines to make it easier to read, but could be collapsed onto one (long) line.  There were some extra machinations to get *just* the md5sum element out of the md5sum command; since the whole "find shell" was wrapped with single quotes, I used double-quotes for the awk script, which meant that the `$` needed to be escaped in order for awk to see `$1` instead of `/some/file/here`.

Answer (score 0):

With a combination of `find` + `wc` + `cut` tools:

```
find /mnt/analysis -type f -size +30000c -size -50000c -exec \
bash -c 's=$(wc -c < "$1"); echo "$1 $(md5sum < "$1" | cut -d" " -f1) $s"' _ '{}' \;
```